# Calling Delphi stdcall function with pAnisChar from node js

Tags: node.js, delphi, node-ffi

I have a legacy Delphi dll which requires a json string as input (pAnsiChar) and returns an int as success or failure. I have managed to connect to the dll from nodejs using node-ffi. However, i am getting return int value points to invalid json string.

Could someone point me in the direction as to how to call a Delphi dll with pAnsiChar as function arguments from node

Thanks

Comment: What about calling convention? My research seems to indicate the node ffi requires cdecl. Do you know different?

Comment: This dll uses stdcall and i can connect to it from other languages such as vba etc. And now i can connect to the dll via node-ffi calls return a value for some functions and was not able to do that on a function that takes json string as PAnsiChar param and returns a json string to a passed PAnsiChar pointer

Comment: I understand that the DLL exports `stdcall` functions. My belief is that node-ffi can only call `cdecl` functions. You accepted Remy's answer which leads me to believe that you have extra information about node-ffi that informs you that node-ffi can in fact call `stdcall` functions. I suppose it is plausible that node-ffi could add some extra code to detect whether or not the callee tidied up the stack and adapt accordingly. What information do you have?

Comment: You seem to be missing my point. As I understand it, node-ffi only supports `cdecl`. Your function is `stdcall`. I presume you read my answer explaining that. You accepted Remy's without commenting on mine. Which I can only assume means that you have information that says that node-ffi supports `stdcall`.

Comment: This is the VBA code `Declare Function JSCall Lib "NETCDFLIB.DLL" (ByVal Req As String, ByVal RetBuf As String, ByVal RetBufLen As Long) As Long` and according to the doco i have, it is a stdcall dll. This dll is used to extract NetCDF data in json format. Unfortunately, in my original email i failed to indicate that it is a stdcall dll and infact, i thought nodejs can only call stdcall dlls only on windows hence not mentioning. Having said that, i was able to get function return call (an int value) which indicated that the req string passed to the dll was invalid jscall hence call for help.

Comment: Your answer was correct too and i suppose you were first to respond -thank you and i appreciate

Comment: I note that you changed the accept. I did not ask for that. I think I would be happier if you put the accept back to Remy's answer. All I meant by my comments is that I am trying to understand whether or not node-ffi does support `cdecl`. It is perfectly plausible that node-ffi supports both `cdecl` and `stdcall` and automatically adjusts to whatever clean up (or not) the callee does. I'd just like to know. I don't want the accept, or up-votes. I just want to understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PAnsiChar` in Delphi is a `char*` in C/C++.  In the FFI declaration for the DLL function, simply declare the `PAnsiChar` parameter as a `"string"`, which is a null-terminated char* in FFI.

For example, given this Delphi function:

```
function ProcessJson(Json: PAnsiChar): Integer; stdcall;
```

The node.js code would look something like this:

```
var ffi = require('ffi');

var mydll = ffi.Library('mydll', {
  'ProcessJson': [ 'int', [ 'string' ] ]
});

var ret = mydll.ProcessJson("json content here");
```

Answer (score 5):

So far as I can tell, Node FFI does not currently allow you to control the calling convention. And the default is `cdecl`. So on the Delphi side it looks like this:

```
function MyFunction(str: PAnsiChar): Integer; cdecl;
```

On the node-ffi side I think it looks like this:

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
var mylib = ffi.Library('libname', {
  'MyFunction': [ 'int', [ 'string' ] ]
});
var retval = mylib.MyFunction("some string");
```

If you cannot modify the legacy DLL then I'm afraid that you may need to wrap it in a DLL that does nothing other than export `cdecl` functions, and then pass them through to the legacy DLL's `stdcall` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into this myself, and based on the research I've done node-ffi can handle the following calling conventions:

> thiscall, fastcall and MSVC cdecl on Windows

Per the [changelog in the readme](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/blob/master/deps/libffi/README#L154).

This isn't the best source of information, but there is no mention of stdcall in the readme.  fastcall is supported though, which is also a callee clean-up calling convention, so it may be best to switch your functions to fastcall instead of cdecl if you're looking to call a Delphi DLL with node-ffi.

I'll try calling some simple StdCall functions through node-ffi to see if it can handle them properly and check back here once I have some results.

Comment: Update: I've had great success using the cdecl calling convention.  See [my DLL project](https://github.com/matortheeternal/xedit-lib) and [my node-ffi bindings](https://github.com/matortheeternal/shampoo/blob/master/src/xelib.js).